# What could cause a blank XML file?

Tags: .net, xml, .net-4.0

I'm using C# with .NET 4.0 and I'm trying to debug a rare problem with my application where sometimes the program will take my .xml file I read and write configuration settings to and will write a blank XML file.

The problem is I can't recreate it after exhaustive attempts to do so, so I thought I might make sure there isn't a known situation where the built in `XmlDocument.Save()` feature could result in a blank file.

The only way the XML file is ever modified is in memory using the built in `XmlNode.AppendChild()` and `XmlNode.ReplaceChild()` so I expect either the problem happens in one of those functions or on write to disk with the `XmlDocument.Save()` function.

Comment: Maybe an unflushed or undisposed stream ?

Comment: @SteveB could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: You don't show code, so this is only a guess. To explain a bit, depending on how you save your xml data, you can have some stream (FileStream, MemoryStream, etc.). .Net internal (and maybe underlying Win32 API, I actually don't know) are buffering the write operation. If for some reason the buffer operation fails, the result ing document may be corrupted. You can also have some cases, when you are nesting a textwriter (or similar) over a stream. If you close the target stream before "flushing" the writer, you are not guaranteed that all data have been written.

Comment: To avoid these situations, always call .Dispose() when you have finished working with these objects. To simplify the code, do not hesitate to use the `using` statement very useful.

Comment: I don't think a stream is being used, I'm using the `.Save("Filename")` override rather than the one where I pass it a stream.

Comment: But you can use `.Save(stream)`

Comment: I've seen the same problem a couple of times recently on a machine where an application was trying to write out to a file on the system drive, and that drive happened to be completely full. I suspect that had something to do with the file being left blank, but I'm not entirely clear on how it could happen and I haven't managed to reproduce it yet, despite attempts.

Answer (score 4):

I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/11535a79-e565-4f6d-bb19-e47054508133) thread.
Especially the second last Answer might be worth a try. Quote:

A workaround which appears to work was to replace:

```
doc.Save("c:\temp\Output.xml")
```

with

```
IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\temp\Output.xml", doc.OuterXml);
```

Comment: This won't work. It'll save only "System.Xml.XmlDocument" string into file.

Comment: This looks promising, I will try to replicate the bug again and if I am able to I will try this fix to see if it works.

Comment: I tried this fix and the bug is still happening, this solution did not work. :(

Comment: It works for me! But why? Where are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

I understood correctly ,you are loading blank xml file and add config seetings and save it back right.

if that is the case you might want to check the write permission on that xml file,sometimes if you don't have permissions it will not write anything into file.

i hope it helps you.

Comment: No the .xml file is never blank to begin with, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I had

```
var infoTableWriter = new XmlTextWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName, new UTF8Encoding(false));
xmlInfoTableDoc.Save(infoTableWriter);
```

without closing the writer, so it saved an Empty (0 bytes) file

```
var infoTableWriter = new XmlTextWriter(saveFileDialog.FileName, new UTF8Encoding(false));
xmlInfoTableDoc.Save(infoTableWriter);
infoTableWriter.Close();
```

works fine. I hope this helps.